# Deploying module as sub domain

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, web-deployment

I want to deploy 3 different modules e.g. admin, staff and user as 
`http://admin.127.0.0.1:8080`
`http://staff.127.0.0.1:8080`
`http://user.127.0.0.1:8080`

I am using eclipse. The question is whether I keep these modules as one project in different folders or deal each module as seprate projects ?

Comment: With subdomains, you would nee to use a dns server in between (or static hostfile entries ). I don't think any IDE offers that.

Comment: How can I do it in Tomcat?